# Have two functions and have to find out parameter A in which functions intersect

Tags: functions

I have two functions and want to find out in which points they intersect

$f(x)=-3x^3-3x^2+Ax$

$g(x)=x^3+x^2-6x$

I know that parameter should be A=18, but it was just my guess. What I want to as you for is the process how to find it.

I know that I must start by $f(x)=g(x)$ and then $f(x)-g(x)=0$ and so on, but I am stuck with quadratic equation with parameter.

Will you help me? :) thx a lot

Comment: You "know that parameter should be A=18" in order that **what** be true?

Comment: Why do you think you are stuck? You have a quadratic equation. What is the discriminat equal to?

Comment: I just guessed that A should be 18, but if it was some other number and I wanted to calculate that. Lets say that 18 is result and you must prove it, not guess it.

Answer (score 1):

y= f(x) and y= g(x) intersect where f(x)= g(x).  Here that is $-3x^3-3x^2+Ax= x^3+x^2-6x$.  The first thing I see is that $x(-3x^2- 3x+ A)= x(x^2+ x- 6)$ so x= 0 is one solution.  If $x\ne 0$ then we can divide both sides by x to get $-3x^2- 3x+ A= x^2+ x- 6$.  We can write that as $4x^2+ 4x- (A+ 6)= 0$.  That is a quadratic equation which has roots $x= \frac{-4\pm \sqrt{16- 4(4)(A+ 6)}}{2(4)}= \frac{-4\pm 4\sqrt{1- A- 6}}{8}$.

Now the question of the number of real roots depends upon the value of $-A- 5$.  If $A= -5$ then $-A- 5= 0$ so the quadratic equation has one real solution and the graphs cross twice.  If $A< -5$ so $-A- 5> 0$ the quadratic equation has two real solutions and the graphs cross three times.  If $A> -5$ so $-A- 5< 0$ so the quadratic equation has no real solutions and the graphs cross only once.